# New field in /proc/stat for CPU

Tags: proc

Today a application that I have crashed. I went to check why and is because a new field in `/proc/stat`:

```
cpu  635570 3943 1264332 13562455 65965 80 4806 0 0 0
cpu0 311689 2102 654770 6755602 32431 38 4127 0 0 0
cpu1 323881 1840 609562 6806853 33534 41 678 0 0 0
```

The last 0 is undocumented, at least in the man page. Does anyone know what is it?

I'm running now in Ubuntu 12.04, and before in 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation hasn't been updated together with the code. You can find out what the new field is in the [source code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.24/fs/proc/stat.c#L42). Field #9 is the time spent running in guest virtual machines hosted by this system; field #10 is the time spent in guests with low priority (#10 is to #9 as #2 is to #1).

As a general design note, when there are multiple fields like this, never assume that the total number of fields is fixed. Ignore any extra field.